# When bonds 'rally' what component is rising? Bond prices? Current yields? Nominal yields? Yield-to-Maturity?

Tags: bonds, fixed-income

As the question says, what should we infer is happening when it's reported that the bond market is surging or rallying?

Is the implication that bond prices are increasing? Or is that yields are increasing, if so, which measure of bond yield?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The price is going up. The bond you own can now be sold for more.

This means that the effective interest rate for someone buying it at this new higher price is **falling** and suggests that buyers are willing to accept a lower interest rate now than you were when you bought it.

Comment: Thanks. What is confusing to me is that in the current environment where a bear market for bonds seems likely, why would bond prices be increasing? If investors or selling off bonds, shouldn't the price go down?

Comment: @StatsScared Are you talking about bonds "rallying" on one particular day? There are always ups and downs. See [here](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/123235/64920) for why markets don't move in a straight line.

Comment: Why do you think a bear market is likely for bonds?

Comment: Thanks. So is the lesson here that when one hears that 'yields' are up, then that's negative for bonds given that bond prices are also up? Or am I confusing the concepts?

Comment: @StatsScared yields up means bond prices down

Comment: "This means that the effective interest rate for someone buying it at this new higher price is falling and suggests that buyers are willing to accept a lower interest rate now than you were when you bought it." Can you elaborate on this? It wasn't clear to me what you were getting at in with your mention of effective interest rate.

Comment: let's say it pays $10 a [unit of time]. If it costs $100 that's 10%. If it costs $110 that is **less** than 10%. Or it will be redeemable at $200 some units of time from now. A person who buys something for 100 and redeems for 200 gets more "interest" than someone who buys for 110 and sells for 200. Whatever way a person gets compensated, a higher price means a lower "interest rate".